# Nearest neighbour distance of points to the point that are not in the same group

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

In my dataset, I have points, whose location are given by `X` and `Y`, that are grouped by `ID`. I want to calculate the nearest neighbour (NN) distance of each point to the points in other groups. In other words, if the `ID` of a point is `1`, the code should search for the NND from the points that satisfy `ID != 1`.

A pseudo-R-code could look like this:

```
DT[DT, c("nn_dist", "nn_X", "nn_Y") := find_NNN(data.table(i.X, i.Y), .SD[ID != i.ID]), by = .EACHI]
```

To achieve this, I tried writing an imperative code with loops and such, but it was too slow. I tried using `get.knnx` function from `FNN` library but then I couldn't figure out how to get both the NN distance and the position of the NN.

How can I do this calculation on a relatively large (~10,000 rows) dataset?

Here is a tiny portion of the dataset I'm using

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), X = c(318L, 317L, 1273L, 
1272L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), t = c(1, 1, 1, 1), uid = c(1L, 
2L, 1271L, 1272L)), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f89b481f0e0>)
```

- `t` column is the same for all of the points in the dataset
- `uid` is a unique id given to every point, regardless of their position or group, so `max(uid)` equals to the #rows in the dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a small distance function that is passed `x`, `y`, and a data frame `d` of all candidate points (i.e. the x and y values of all the points in other id groups, and returns the coordinates and uid of the nearest inter-group point

```
dist <- function(x,y,d) d[order(d[,sqrt((X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2)])][1]
```

Then apply the function to the frame

```
df[, c("nnX", "nnY", "nn"):=dist(X,Y, df[ID!=.BY$ID,.(X,Y,uid)]),by=.(ID,uid)]
```

Output:

```
   ID    X Y t  uid  nnX nnY   nn
1:  1  318 1 1    1 1272   2 1272
2:  1  317 2 1    2 1272   2 1272
3:  2 1273 1 1 1271  318   1    1
4:  2 1272 2 1 1272  318   1    1
```

If you additionally want the distance to that nearest neighbor, you could either update the function and the call to the function like this:

```
dist <- function(x,y,d) {
  d[, nn_dist:=sqrt((X-x)^2 + (Y-y)^2)][order(nn_dist)][1]
}
df[, c("nnX", "nnY", "nn", "nn_dist"):=dist(X,Y, df[ID!=.BY$ID,.(X,Y,uid)]),by=.(ID,uid)]
```

Output:

```
   ID    X Y t  uid  nnX nnY   nn  nn_dist
1:  1  318 1 1    1 1272   2 1272 954.0005
2:  1  317 2 1    2 1272   2 1272 955.0000
3:  2 1273 1 1 1271  318   1    1 955.0000
4:  2 1272 2 1 1272  318   1    1 954.0005
```

or, you could use the first function and estimate the distance at the end using `df[, nn_dist := sqrt((X-nnX)^2 + (Y-nnY)^2)]`

Answer (score 1):

I once had to do a similar job.

The `nncross` function in the `spatstat` library can do this work. I don't know how to use data.table, but the following example code should be easy to follow.

```
library(spatstat)

# create an example dataframe of 100 points that belong to 10 classes
points <- data.frame(X=rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                     Y=rnorm(100, mean = 0, sd = 1),
                     class_id = sample(1:10, size = 100, replace = T))

# convert the dataframe of points to ppp object that can be used as input for nncross function
points.ppp <- as.ppp(points, 
                     W=owin( xrange = range(points$X),yrange = range(points$Y) )
                     )

# calculate for each points its NN point that belongs to another class. The "iX" and "iY" arguments are very important to tell the function to calculate only the cross-class distance, please see the help information of the nncross function for details.
NND_which <- nncross(points.ppp,
                 points.ppp,
                 iX = as.integer(points.ppp$marks), 
                 iY = as.integer(points.ppp$marks)
                 )

# put the NN pairs as well as the distance between them in a new dataframe
NND_pair <- data.frame(NND_source_id = 1:nrow(points),
                       NND_target_id = NND_which$which,
                       NND_dist = NND_which$dist)
```

This function should be much faster than loops in R. But if you have extremely large number of points, say billions of points, I recommend writing your own function in C++, with the help of Rcpp.

I don't know the `FNN` library, probably someone else who knows how to use it can compare which function is faster.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is generally best to use the OP's data, since it was provided, to demonstrate the utility of your approach, here `spatstat`, so that they get the comforting sense that their problem is being solved. You might adjust you answer towards their data. Otherwise, nicely written code for some problem.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Sorry I wouldn't put more effort into this, as I stated at the beginning, "I don't know how to use data.table, but the following example code should be easy to follow", I am trying to give a hint and carefully added the comments in the code to make it easier to follow.  The OP should be able to figure out how to curate the data. By the way, the accepted answer is really nice and elegant, and advanced, I learnt from it.