# Interpolate from the color of single points to areas

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have 2D design containing some rectangles, and I have the coordinates of the boundaries of those rectangles. I'm first calculating the wall-to-wall distance between these boundaries, given by `nn_dist` in the dataset, and then plotting these boundary points as a heatmap, where the color represents the `nn_dist` value of each boundary point.

Here is the code to plot that (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72177631/6708910) for how `nn_dist` is calculated).

```
ggplot(dt, aes(x=Y, y=X, z=wall_to_wall_dist)) +
  stat_summary_hex(fun=min, bins=500)+
  #geom_raster(aes(fill = wall_to_wall_dist), interpolate = TRUE)+
  #geom_tile()+
  xlim(c(0,10000))+
  ylim(c(0,3800))+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = myPalette, limits = c(100,300))+
  theme_default(s_aspectRatio=3800/10000, text_font_size = fontSize)
```

Here a section from the output:

[image]

However, as you can see, most of the plot look empty and it is hard get any intuition from this plot about the wall-to-wall distance information between the rectangles. As a result, I want to fill the empty space between the boundaries in a way that it is interpolated from the color of the boundary points.

How can I do this?
In the end the output should, sort of, look like

[image]

Here is a tiny part of the dataset (~100,000 rows) that I'm using:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), X = c(318L, 317L, 316L, 
315L, 314L, 313L, 312L, 311L, 310L, 309L, 1273L, 1272L, 1271L, 
1270L, 1269L, 1268L, 1267L, 1266L, 1265L, 1264L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L), t = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), uid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1271L, 1272L, 1273L, 1274L, 1275L, 1276L, 1277L, 1278L, 
1279L, 1280L), nnX = c(1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 
1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 
318L, 318L, 318L, 318L), nnY = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    wall_to_wall_dist = c(946.042810870629, 947.033790315847, 
    948.025843529595, 949.018967144493, 950.013157803617, 951.008412160481, 
    952.004726879021, 953.002098633576, 954.000524108871, 955, 
    955, 954.000524108871, 953.002098633576, 952.004726879021, 
    951.008412160481, 950.013157803617, 949.018967144493, 948.025843529595, 
    947.033790315847, 946.042810870629)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fce30813ce0>)
```

- `X,Y` represent the location of the boundary points
- `nnX, nnY` represent the nearest neighbour boundary point that is not on the same rectangle, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72177631/6708910)
- `nn_dist` is the distance between `X,Y` and `nnX, nnY`
- `ID` a unique id for each rectangle
- `uid` a unique id for each boundary point, regardless of the rectangle they are on

Comment: Does your design start out with just corner co-ordinates? If so, it might be best to post a chunk of these covering a contiguous 2D area. That way, we could have a think about alternate approaches that might be more effective.

Comment: Dear @AllanCameron , No, actually, I am using a MATLAB script to extract the boundary points from the design first. Then importing them to R.
And, in fact, eventually I will first extract the boundary points of some structures from experimental data, and then do the plotting. That is why, for the purpose of this question, the best starting point if the boundary coordinates.

Comment: @AllanCameron But if it helps, you could assume that we have the position of individual connected components, not just their boundary points - i.e the boundary + inner-region of the rectangular blocks.

Answer (score 0):

w.l.o.g., one can rotate the plot to have an example with easier coordinates.
Let points contain one corner point of any rectangle per row.
The Voronoi partition will create areas of points with the same the nearest edge point. This can be used to interpolate the edge colors:

```r
remotes::install_github("garretrc/ggvoronoi")

library(ggvoronoi)
#> Loading required package: ggplot2
library(tidyverse)

# corner points of the rectangles
points <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y, ~rect,
  0, 0, "A",
  1, 0, "A",
  1, 1, "A",
  0, 1, "A",
  2, 0, "B",
  3, 0, "B",
  2, 1, "B",
  3, 1, "B"
)

rects <-
  points %>%
  group_by(rect) %>%
  summarise(
    xmin = min(x),
    xmax = max(x),
    ymin = min(y),
    ymax = max(y)
  )
rects
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   rect   xmin  xmax  ymin  ymax
#>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A         0     1     0     1
#> 2 B         2     3     0     1

points %>%
  mutate(rect = rect %>% factor()) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_voronoi(aes(x, y, fill = rect)) +
  geom_rect(
    data = rects,
    mapping = aes(xmin = xmin, ymin = ymin, xmax = xmax, ymax = ymax),
    fill = "white"
  ) +
  geom_point(aes(x, y))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-05-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: but do note that, even points that are adjecent to each other can have different colors, as they have different wall to wall distances.

Comment: and also do note that, the actual dataset on which this code will run contains ~100,000 rows, so i can't possibly do what you did with `tribble` there

Comment: tribble is just for example data. you might want to use the dplyr package to construct the data.frame points. You can also create another column called edge_color and do `geom_voronoi(aes(fill=edge_color))`allowing have multiple colors mixed within a rect.

Comment: Thank you for the effort, but rotating the rectangles is not something that is acceptable for my analysis, as the dataset is a representation of an experimental data.

Comment: The answer does not use properties inherent to rotation and thus is applicable to your data as well.

Comment: Could you then show me an example without using a rotation?

Comment: That's what I did