# two-point Voronoi diagram

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataset containing pair of points in a 2D space (`X,Y,nnX,nnY` columns). I want to create a Voronoi diagram using these pairs of points such that each each partition will contain exactly two points. Then color the partitions using the columns `wall_to_wall_dist` column.

How can I do this in ggplot?

I did some research and it seems there is something called [two-point Voronoi diagram](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X01003201) or [partial Voronio diagrams](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1571066104803815?via%3Dihub) in theory but couldn't figure out how to do it in practice.

Here is a tiny part of the dataset (~100,000 rows) that I'm using:

```
structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), X = c(318L, 317L, 316L, 
315L, 314L, 313L, 312L, 311L, 310L, 309L, 1273L, 1272L, 1271L, 
1270L, 1269L, 1268L, 1267L, 1266L, 1265L, 1264L), Y = c(1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L), t = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), uid = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 1271L, 1272L, 1273L, 1274L, 1275L, 1276L, 1277L, 1278L, 
1279L, 1280L), nnX = c(1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 
1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 1264L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 318L, 
318L, 318L, 318L, 318L), nnY = c(10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
    wall_to_wall_dist = c(946.042810870629, 947.033790315847, 
    948.025843529595, 949.018967144493, 950.013157803617, 951.008412160481, 
    952.004726879021, 953.002098633576, 954.000524108871, 955, 
    955, 954.000524108871, 953.002098633576, 952.004726879021, 
    951.008412160481, 950.013157803617, 949.018967144493, 948.025843529595, 
    947.033790315847, 946.042810870629)), row.names = c(NA, -20L
), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7fce30813ce0>)
```

- `X,Y` represent the location of the boundary points
- `nnX, nnY` represent the nearest neighbour boundary point that is not on the same rectangle, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72177631/6708910)
- `wall_to_wall_dist` is the distance between `X,Y` and `nnX, nnY`
- `ID` a unique id for each rectangle
- `uid` a unique id for each boundary point, regardless of the rectangle they are on

Comment: But you have multiple instances of the same physical point (like [nnX, nnY) for the first 10 rows). How could you arrange the tiling to have only two points in each region if there are multiple points in an identical location?

Comment: @AllanCameron If there are multiple `X,Y` that are mapped to the same `nnX,nnY`, then just keep only the first pair and drop the rest

Comment: Take a look at the `ggvoronoi` package